# Instantiate class from known type

Tags: java, android

I have an array that stores types of classes.

These are then instantiated in the order the are associated with.

```
public static class ViewHolderViewTypeStorage {
        private int layout;
        private Class<? extends BaseViewHolder> classType;
        public ViewHolderViewTypeStorage(int layout, Class<? extends BaseViewHolder> classType) {
            this.layout = layout;
            this.classType = classType;
        }

        public int getLayout() {
            return layout;
        }

        public Class<? extends BaseViewHolder> getClassType() {
            return classType;
        }
    }
```

Then they are requested

```
ViewHolderViewTypeStorage viewHolderViewTypeStorage = viewHolderViewTypeStorageMap.get(viewType);
View newViewGroup = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewHolderViewTypeStorageMap.get(viewType).getLayout(), parent, false);

//The problem code
return viewHolderViewTypeStorage.getClassType().getDeclaredConstructor(viewHolderViewTypeStorage.getClassType()).newInstance(newViewGroup);
```

My problem is, is that it's not working. I get the following error:

```
<init> [class my.app.mainui.ViewHolderLatestChangeTask]
```

I also tried with

```
viewHolderViewTypeStorage.getClassType().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(newViewGroup);
```

Error message was

```
<init> []
```

Any ideas, i'm stuck :-S

Heres the solution.

```
return viewHolderViewTypeStorage.getClassType().getDeclaredConstructor(new Class<?>[]{View.class}).newInstance(newViewGroup);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Class.getDeclaredConstructor()` you have to pass to it an array of parameter types each of type `Class<?>` in order for reflection to pinpoint the exact constructur you are after.

So your first attempt was on a right track, but try calling `getDeclaredContructor()` passing to it an array rather than a single class:
`Class.getDeclaredContructor(new Class<?>[]{viewHolderViewTypeStorage.getClassType()})`